# Exception in SocketOpenofficeConnection

Tags: java

```
File file = new File((new StringBuilder()).append(s2).append(File.separator).append(s1).toString());

file.renameTo(new File((new StringBuilder()).append(s2).append(File.separator).append("$$tsjoof$$.ppt").toString()));

SocketOpenOfficeConnection socketopenofficeconnection = new SocketOpenOfficeConnection();
```

I am importing `.ppt` file but it is giving an exception on `SocketOpenOfficeConnection` as:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/apache/poi/POIDocument
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.apache.poi.POIDocument

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
```

I have also imported `poi-2.5.1.jar,poi-scratchpad-3.1-FINAL.jar,ridl-2.4.1.jar,xbean-1.0.3.jar` please give me some solution for that.

Comment: Have you imported `slf4j`?

Comment: @qiGuar which version you are saying? any link you have?

Comment: Add the latest version. You can download from here http://www.slf4j.org/download.html

Comment: @qiGuar yes thanks .but still it is giving same exception

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory` should have disappeared. Are you sure this jar is in classpath?

Comment: @ qiGuar where i shuould need to check this file